# Text similarity score using a single query on a single document in Gensim

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf

What I am trying to do is get a score of the likelihood of a search/query term in a single document/text/paragraph.

The score should tell how much the text is talking about the query term.

Here is what I have tried but failed:

```
def score(text_data,query):

    texts = [str(doc).encode('utf-8').lower().split() for doc in text_data]

    dictionary = Dictionary(texts)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(line) for line in texts]

    tfidf_model = TfidfModel(corpus)

    query_vec = dictionary.doc2bow(query.lower().split())
    query_vec = tfidf_model[query_vec]

    index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf_model[corpus])

    x = tfidf_model[query_vec]
    sims = index[x]
    score = list(sims)

    return score
```

I only need 1 value of the likelihood of the search term in the text data, between 0 to 1. What am I doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Can you provide your output?

Comment: it is a list of 0s : [0,0,0....] the number of zeros correspond to the number of words in the text, I suppose